# Is this possible in cocos2dx 3.0?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a number of five images (`sprite1.png, sprite2.png, sprite3.png, sprite4.png, sprite5.png`), these all I want to add as a sprite...

```
int rndSprtNum = (arc4random() % 5) + 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int rndSprtNum = (arc4random() % 5) + 1;
    CCSprite *first = CCSprite::create("sprite%d.png",rndSprtNum);

    rndSize = rndSize+(arc4random() % 20) + 15;
    int  width = rndSize + 125*(size.width/768);
    rndSize = rndSize + 90;
    first->setPosition(ccp(width,512 * (size.height/1024)));

    this->addChild(first,0);
}
```

Is this possible in cocos2dx v3.0?

Answer (score 1):

How did you get the idea that you could use CCSprite::create like that? the correct syntax would be:

```
CCSprite::create(CCString::createWithFormat("sprite%d.png", rndSprtNum)->getCString());
```

Other than that your code seems to be fine, except I don't get what it's supposed to do, which is a little bit alerting.

Seriously, did you even try compiling that code? You should get a compile error...

Comment: Thank you brother ... i am new in cocos2d so i does not have a syntax knowledge...

Comment: @Dhruv-user3531484 you can always google stuff, and you can use the engine documentation. I mean you should have gotten a compile error for that code...

Answer (score 0):

The question refers to **cocos2d-x 3.0**. `CCSprite` has been deprecated in favor of `Sprite` and the `CCString` in favor of `std::string`. Actually, most methods in recent versions, accept only `std::string` and the prefix `CC` has been deprecated from most classes.

Therefore the following would be correct (and not deprecated):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "sprite" << rndSprtNum << ".png";
Sprite *first = Sprite::create(oss.str());
```

Comment: Thanks. I mean it. I also think that's the ugliest string handling code I have ever seen again in my life. :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you need to use CCString, it is now __String in Cocos2d-x v3. This will have all the same functions, also a great way to find the new versions is typing in the deprecated version aka CCString thne right clicking it and pressing jump to definition.

Comment: Please add context to the answer. This is not the place to advertise, thanks.